# What should I learn to understand 6d (2,0) theory?

Tags: field-theory, supersymmetry, education, spacetime-dimensions

I'm a first-year graduate student, I heard that 6d (2,0) theories can provide various dualities between lower dimension field theories, and can give many beautiful results in mathematics.

So I decided to learn it, and I found a review , then I found there exists many unfamiliar mathematical concepts, such as Calabi-Yau manifold, and something like algebric geometry.

So how should I arrange my study? I plan to learn supersymmetry by the book written by Wess and Bagger,should I learn some math at the same time?